# 2 steps for remote partition - spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to configure 2 steps in spring batch where the first step is remotely partitioned and the second should be executed after each partition is executed. Can anyone help me with this?

I am thinking something like this:

```
<job id="job1">
 <step id="step1.master"/>
 <next on="*" to="step2"/>
 <step id="step2"/>
</job>
```

The step1.master will have a partitioned step. After each partition step is completed, I want to invoke the step2 for other processing. Is the next on="*" available for the remote partitioned step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the sequential flow you defined is correct.

> Is the next on="*" available for the remote partitioned step?

yes, the flow will execute steps in sequence as you defined them regardless if step1 is executed remotely or locally, partitioned or not.